# How to write a function defined for a subset of all enumeration values?

Tags: scala, enumeration

Suppose I've got enumeration `A` :

```
object A extends Enumeration { type A = Int; val A1 = 1; val A2 = 2; val A3 = 3 }
```

Also, I have a function defined only for `A1` or `A2` but not for `A3`.

```
def foo(a: A): Int = a match { 
  case A.A1 => 1 // do something 
  case A.A2 => 2 // do something else 
  case A.A3 => throw new UnsupportedOperationException() 
}
```

Now I would like to get a compilation error for `foo(A.A3)`.
In pseudocode I define `foo` like this:

```
def foo(a: A1 | A2): Int = ???
```

How would you suggest write `foo` to prevent calling it with `A.A3` ?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I suggest avoiding `Enumeration` and instead defining `trait A` and sub-types for each of the enumeration values. Then you can use a typeclass to define a specific sets of elements (or a union type in Scala 3)

Comment: Which Scala? If you have Scala 3 you CAN use `type ASubset = A1 | A2` as type definition. But if you have Scala 3 then there is even better argument to avoid `Enumeration` - `enum A { case A1, A2, A3 }`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok `A1` is a value not a type, so you can't use a union type with this code even in Scala 3 (where, as you say, `enum` would be a better solution).

Comment: Well, you could if you replaced `A1` with `A1.type`. As a matter of the fact, that's how parameterless `case` values are implemented in `enum`s in Scala 3 - `val A1 = new A`. They are not `case object`s, they are not even `object`s, they are `val`s referred to as singleton types with `value.type` annotation (as I got painfully aware handling them in macros). So `type Subtype = A1.type | A2.type` [works perfectly](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tM1dtCw6Sq65uYja91SPwQ).

Comment: As @MateuszKubuszok suggested and using your pseudo-code, you could do `def foo(x: A.A1.type | A.A2.type): Int = ???`

Comment: It's Scala 3-only solution though. For Scala 2 you'd either have to create an extra `sealed trait A12 extends A` or use some wild type evidence (I don't recommend it).

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. Just forgot to mention I need a solution for Scala 2. I can refactor the code including the `A` definition but I want the changes to be minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given pseudo code is on the right track; the supported types need to be in the type signature of `foo` and unsupported types not.

```scala
// Scala 3

object A extends Enumeration {
  type A = Int
  val A1 = 1
  val A2 = 2
  val A3 = 3
}

def foo(a: A.A1.type | A.A2.type): Int = 1

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  foo(A.A1)
  foo(A.A3)
}
```

Compilation error:

```
Found:    (A.A3 : Int)
Required: (A.A1 : Int) | (A.A2 : Int)
  foo(A.A3)
```

To make this possible in scala 2 (literal types needed, so only scala 2.13 or Typelevel's 2.12) we need give a more refined type to the `A1`-`A3` constants, and an implicit conversion to the 'union' type `A12`:

```scala
object A extends Enumeration {
  type A = Int
  val A1: 1 = 1
  val A2: 2 = 2
  val A3: 3 = 3

  sealed trait A12 { val a: A }
  private case class AnA12(a: A) extends A12
  implicit def a1ToA12(a1: 1): A12 = AnA12(a1)
  implicit def a2ToA12(a2: 2): A12 = AnA12(a2)
}

object Foo {
  import A._

  def foo(a: A12): Int = a.a

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    foo(A1)
    foo(A3)
  }
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : 3
 required: Foo.A12
    foo(A3)
```

`AnA12` is private to make it impossible to use `foo(AnA12(A3))`.

Comment: Thanks but I should have written that I need a solution for Scala 2.

Comment: @Michael I have added a solution for scala 2